# C# desktop app gives error when accessing Access database (mdb)

Tags: c#, ms-access, thread-safety, ms-access-2007

I'm writing a desktop application in C#. It's using an MS Access mdb database. From time to time I'm getting strange errors like the one below. I have a few threads accessing the database but they all lock the access (with the `lock()` keyword).

This is driving me nuts because I don't even know what could cause the errors and where to look for the cause. Anyone had similar experience and could give me any hints?

This one showed up when the app tried to read some data from the database:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Internal .Net Framework Data
>   Provider error 12.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CreateReferenceCollection()
>   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.AddWeakReference(Object
>   value, Int32 tag)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.AddWeakReference(Object value, Int32
>   tag)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   nscm.DBManager.RetrieveUpdates(Int32 lastRetrievedUpdateId) in
>   c:\Users\myaccount\WORKSPACE\SharpDevelop_Projects\myapp\Classes_Data\DBManager.cs:line
>   567

Comment: Please see the following link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/0859dee9-6a1c-484c-9bcb-41fca3c0b938/

Comment: This strongly points to not protecting your shared variables well enough with a lock.  Very hard to diagnose of course, tackle it by restructuring your code and giving each thread its own connection object.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that forum thread when I was trying to find a solution myself. The strange thing is, I don't have any shared connections. every method in ma db management singleton class opens and closes its own connection. Neither of them uses a connection created by another method and neither passes a connection to another method. I'm totally confused!
Is it possible that a connection somehow is doesn't get completely closed after connection.Close()? Should I dispose of it somehow. I thought it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, I've solved the problem. I have two separate mdb files for my app and two separate background threads - each of them accessing their own mdb file respectively (one thread uses one file, the other one the other file). My wrong assumption in the beginning was that if these threads work separately and access separate files there will be no problem.

Unfortunately it turns out that in your application there can be ONLY ONE CONNECTION TO ANY DATABASE FILE AT ANY MOMENT.

Now I'm locking access to all files with just one lock for all threads (so only one thread can access any file) and I'm not getting the error anymore!

Specific code example for those who run into the same problem:

```
Object dbLock = new Object(); //make it a field in the database managing singleton class
```

In a method used by any thread use:

```
lock(dbLock) //lock out db access from other threads (reserve for this thread only)
{
   //here goes some code which will run only when the thread manages to lock the dbLock
   //this code should accesses your database by creating and opening
   //a new connection and then closing it in the same block
}
```

Once this block finishes, another method can lock access to the database the same way

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd place a `try catch` block in your `DBManager` class around line 567, in order to catch some more meaningful data.

It will also allow you to place a breakpoint in the exception handling block so that you can see what live data is being used prior to the exception being thrown.

Multithreaded access to a database from within the same application can get problematical, especially with Access.

For this reason most people access the database via a singleton class.

It is possible that you're encountering an exception due to locking conflicts when retrieving data from the database.

Comment: **1.** I've got try-catch blocks and I know at which point the error shows up but I don't understand the error and don't know what the real cause could be.
**2.** Breakpoint - the error doesn't always appear at the same point and at the same time. Happens only sometimes, when the app is accessing the database. Sometimes works fine for 0.5h and then throws the error
**3.** DBManager is a singleton. All methods which access the database are in this class
**4.** What do you mean, "locking conflicts"?

Comment: Looks like you've covered most of the bases. As you didn't give much information about your code I had to make general statements. Is it always the same error thrown?

Comment: I don't know which piece of code to post and posting the whole code is pointless so I hoped that someone would have encountered the same error and knew the solution.
Yes, I think (but am not sure) that it's the same error every time

Comment: Just happened again. Same error. In the method which gets some data from a table in the database. I have several methods, which get data from different tables from db and the error shows up in most of those methods.